# Pass ID list using ajax call to ViewModel with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

In my web service (order.asmx) I have a method which accept a viewmodel as a parameter. Method signature is below.

```
public string CreateOrder(OrderModel order)
```

and my order.cs is like below,

```
public class OrderModel: BaseClass
{
    public OrderModel()
    {
        this.RestaurantIDs = new List<long>();
    }

    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public List<long> RestaurantIDs { get; set; }
}
```

I'm passing all the order related details using ajax call to this service method. To pass the RestaurantIDs I'm using an array which gives me 500 server error. I tried with stringify as well but didnt work. Anyone can help me with this?

ajax call

```
function createOrderObject()
{
    var order = new object;
    order.CustomerName = $("#txtName").val();
    order.RestaurantIDs = selectedRestaurants.map(function (obj) {
                        return obj.RestaurantID;
                    });
}

// here the selectedRestaurants is object array.

function createOrder()
{
    var order = createOrderObject();
    var url = '/Service/OrderService.asmx/CreateOrder';
    var dataSet = '{orderModel:' + JSON.stringify(order) + '}';

    var orderInfo = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: url,
    data: dataSet,
    dataType: "json",
    error: function () {
        giveNotification({ NotificationCode: 500, Message: "Internal Server Error, Please try again." });
        loadingImg(ele, "hide");           
    });
}
```

the error message [image: 500 Error]}

Comment: What does the `create` refer to in `var order = create`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Sorry it was a typing mistake. I have corrected it